# fillText not available on OffscreenCanvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I seem to be having trouble rendering text to an OffscreenCanvas (in Chrome 61.0.3). Is the method missing or is there something I need to do to get this working?

```
const oOffscreenCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(480,480);
const oOffscreenContext = oOffscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

oOffscreenContext.fillStyle = 'red';
oOffscreenContext.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
oOffscreenContext.fillStyle = 'white';
oOffscreenContext.fillText('help', 32, 32);
```

.... produces....

> Uncaught TypeError: oOffscreenContext.fillText is not a function

Comment: Use the console to view the 2D context object `console.log(oOffscreenContext).` On my chrome (current beta 6/10/2017 (au date)) ) The following are missing in regards to text.  `ctx.font`, `ctx.fillText`, `ctx.strokeText`, `ctx.measureText`, `ctx.textAlign`, `ctx.textBaseline` If they will ever be supported I can not say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the text API isn't available at the time of writing this question